# How to conditionally apply jQuery Sortable UI widget to table (ASP.NET GridView)?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following code which applies the jQuery UI Sortable plugin to all tables (GridView) on an ASP.NET page, excluding the first (header) row in each:

```
function pageLoad() {
    $('table').sortable({
        items: 'tr:not(:first)',
        axis: 'y',
        scroll: true,
        start: startDrag, //store start position
        stop: stopDrag    //get end position, update database
    }).disableSelection();
```

However I only want to apply sortable to a table if there is more than one row (in addition to the header row) otherwise the drag/drop functionality is redundant.

How can I conditionally apply the above only to tables having more than one content row? Thanks.

Comment: This is great, and very timely as I need something just like it.  2 Questions to add:  1) startDrag is undefined.  I assume I need to declare it in codebehind but what data type?  2) I am using this to allow the user to resort an ordered list based on an 'order' column (int).  Is there an efficient way to save this back to the database?

Comment: Maybe a better question is how can I read the new positions in the gridview.  When I swap items 0 and 1, and read gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text it still shows the original item.  Not sure how to read the post-sort items in each position.

Comment: you can check the regular jquery `index()` of the dropped element, or export the full position state using `sortable.serialize()` : http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize

Comment: @nycdan see my answer below re. how to handle the reordering.

Comment: @James McCormack Thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jquery `filter()` provides a solution. It allows you to filter a set of matched elements using a test function. Therefore the following code applies `sortable` only to tables that have more than one data row:

```
function pageLoad() {

    $('table').filter(function () {
                        return $('tr', this).length > 2;
                      })
              .sortable({
                 items: 'tr:not(:first)',
                 axis: 'y',
                 scroll: true,
                 start: startDrag, //store start position
                 stop: stopDrag    //get end position, update database
                 })
              .disableSelection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to nydcan's queries above, the startDrag method looks like this:

```
 function startDrag(event, ui) {
    var startIndex = ui.item.index();
    ui.item.data('startIndex', startIndex);
}
```

And the stopDrag method looks like this:

```
function stopDrag(event, ui) {
    var startIndex = ui.item.data('startIndex');
    var endIndex = ui.item.index();
    if (startIndex != endIndex) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/MyPage.aspx/UpdateOrder") %>',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: "{ 'startIndex':'" + startIndex + "', 'endIndex':'" + endIndex + "'}",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: updateSuccess,
            error: updateError
        });
    }
}
```

I then have a web method (VB.NET) on my page like this:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Sub UpdateRulePriority(ByVal startIndex As Integer, ByVal endIndex As Integer)

    'Do stuff

End Sub
```

Hope that helps.